# Replacing elements of a list using a pure function fails; why?

Tags: list-manipulation, pure-function

I have this list:

> {{5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12, 13, 14}, {15, 16, 17, 18, 19}, {20, 21,
>   22, 23, 24}, {25, 26, 27, 28, 29}}

For learning purposes I try to replace one number (random) in each sublist with "a". I try to do it by using a pure function, but I get an error when using this code:

```
mylist = Range[5 #, 5 # + 4] & /@ Range[5]
i = Random[Integer, {1, 5}]
mylist[[#, i]] & /@ Range[1, 5] = a
```

Why do I get an error and what should I do instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list = Partition[Range[5, 29], 5];

SeedRandom[1]

(list[[#, RandomInteger[{1, 5}]]] = a) & /@ Range@Length@list
```

or

```
ReplacePart[list, i_ :> {list[[i, RandomInteger[{1, 5}]]] = a}]
```

or

```
MapThread[(list[[##]] = a) &, {Range@5, RandomInteger[{1, 5}, 5]}]
```

all give

```
list // MatrixForm
```

[image]

If you want to replace at the same position it would simply be

```
list[[All, RandomInteger[{1, 5}]]] = a;

list // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are trying to `Set` the entirety of `mylist[[#, i]] & /@ Range[1, 5]` to `a`.  This expression really looks like

```
Map[mylist[[#, i]] &, Range[1, 5]] = a
```

which means you are trying to associate a definition with `Map`, which is a protected function, just like

```
f[something] = a
```

associates a definition with `f`.  Evaluating the expression first doesn't work either, i.e.

```
Evaluate[mylist[[#, i]] & /@ Range[1, 5]] = a
```

because the left-hand side evaluates to `{a, a, a, a, a}`, which is the same as `List[a, a, a, a, a]`, and then you are trying to associate a definition with `List`, which is protected as well.

Here's how you would make it work using your idea: `(mylist[[#, i]] = a) & /@ Range[1, 5]`.

Here's the most straight-forward way:

```
mylist[[All, i]] = a
```

Answer (score 4):

A better explanation as why was given by [march](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/151843/34129).

To fix your code you can simply reorder your last line:

```
(mylist[[#,i]]=a)&/@Range[1,5]
```

But it is simpler. You can use multiple targets in one reference, just do:

```
mylist[[Range[1, 5], i]] = a
```

---

**BTW:
Random[Integer,...] is deprecated!**

***Use RandomInteger instead!***